# Как без помощи автоматического DML сделать вставку файла в BLOB колонку?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

При добавлении поля загрузки файла "File Browse ..." в APEX добавляю две сущности: `P1_FILENAME` и `P1_DOCDATA`.

Когда загружаем/обновляем файл при помощи автоматического процесса Automatic Row Processing (DML), то все корректно в БД сохраняется и обновляется. Но как только я пытаюсь сделать вставку/обновление в пользовательском процессе в виде:

```
insert into T_SPORTS (ID, FILENAME, DOCDATA) values (
    :P1_ID, :P1_FILENAME, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(:P1_DOCDATA))
```

, то добавленный таким образом файл выглядит как битый, т.е. запрос:

```
  select lenght(DOCDATA) from T_SPORTS where ID = 123
```

покажет, что данные в поле таблицы сохранились, но считать и отобразить их на странице корректно не получается (`P1_FILENAME` будет пустым, и ссылка на скачивание файла неактивна).

Как можно сделать вставку файла в таблицу пользовательским скриптом, чтобы он потом корректно отображался на странице?

Может быть *Automatic Row Processing (DML)* при добавлении записи еще какую-то предварительную обработку для BLOB колонки проводит?

Comment: А вы пробовали тут поиском ответ найти? Например [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+insert+blob). Ничего не помогло?

Comment: А что у вас в `P1_DOCDATA` содержится?

Comment: Поиск аналогичного примера со вставкой файла в БД скриптом, к сожалению, не дал результатов

Comment: Поиск не дал результата, или найденое и опробованное не дало желаемого результата? Я уже давал ответ, вы скорее всего его видели, но удалил его, т.к. мне показалось, что он вам мало поможет.

Comment: Сущность P1_DOCDATA содержит прикрепляемый файл, т.е. как я понимаю, что там хранится сам файл (и служебная информация по нему) в формате BLOB. При этом Automatic Row Processing (DML) при обновлении записи извлекает имя файла и автоматически сохраняет его в сущности  P1_FILENAME. Хотелось бы понять, как можно корректно в скрипте сделать эту же манипуляцию: и файл как надо сохранить, и имя файла определить и положить в нужное поле таблицы БД

Comment: Да, спасибо, я  видела ваш ответ, проанализировала его, но пока не знаю, как применить этот подход в своей задаче. Других вариантов пока не нашлось(если только снова возвращать Automatic Row Processing (DML)) .Но зато сейчас хотя бы появилась ясность с тем, как все устроено и в какую сторону искать

Comment: _P1_DOCDATA содержит прикрепляемый файл_. ну файл она не может содержать, вы имели ввиду данные из файла. Если так, то зачем вы  используете UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW? Попробуйте без него.

Comment: Да, все верно - данные из файла. А без CAST_TO_RAW ошибка получается. BLOB-поле как раз корректно сработает в инструкции `INSERT INTO...` если используется UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW

Comment: Пока не совсем понял, что вы понимаете под скриптом? Это PL/SQL блок или SQL?

Comment: Это PL/SQL блок. В нем буду делать дополнительные проверки и заодно вставку записи в таблицу (тот самый `insert into T_SPORTS...`)

Comment: А где лежат файлы, которые вы хотите вставить, локально или на сервере?

Comment: Локально. Это файл с компьютера пользователя, который он будет подкреплять к своей учетной записи

Comment: Понял. Задача не тривиальная, т.к. нет стандартных функций, которые читают локальные файлы. PL/SQL блоком вы не обойдётесь, т.к. он может читать только на сервере. Скорее всего, надо посмотреть в сторону локальных  скриптов, Perl или Python, или .bat с SQL*Loader.

Comment: А почему вы решили отказаться от того, что APEX предлагет для загрузки файлов, а хотите тоже самое сделать вручную? Вам же придётся тоже самое програмировать. Какой смысл, или чего там не хватает?

Comment: Там до вставки записи выполняются функции/процедуры, которые проверяют, можно ли добавлять эту запись или же нет. Стандартная вставка DML не позволит провести эти проверки ДО добавления записи в БД